# Expand All Nodes on Lazyload in Jquery dynatree

Tags: jquery, dynatree

I am using Dyna Tree plugin for tree view.

Now, while expanding the parent node I am using lazy load function,

```
onLazyRead: function(node){
    node.appendAjax({
    url: TREEVIEW_JSON_URL
    });
}
```

Now I would like to expand all the child and sub-child nodes those are available in my response with lazyLoad. In the current scenario I am able to expand only child nodes.

Please help me out on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this (haven't tested it though):

```
$("#tree").dynatree({
    […]
    onLazyRead: function(node){
        node.appendAjax({url: TREEVIEW_JSON_URL,
                         success: function(node) {
                             // Called after nodes have been created and the waiting icon was removed.
                             // now expand all children
                             node.visit(function(n){
                                 n.expand(true);
                                 });
                             }
                         });
    },
    […]
});
```

Comment: Hi there, Sorry for the late reply. My services are down to test your sample suggestion. using the code you suggested, Tree levels are expanded but also it's children nodes are getting called through ajax lazy loading. Is there any way to stop those ajax calls and expand only till the data exist.

Comment: You could call `node.hasChildren()` to check if child nodes are present. You could also let the server add `"expand": true` to the JSON data, which would be the most efficient way (no JavaScript required).